# Choosing a framework for both app and website

Tags: rest, reactjs, meteor, web-applications, react-native

There is an old php base website which provides a single service and is working for many years. Now we have decided to change the website itself to become more modern and faster and at the same time providing an app for it and we are going to hire some people for that. As I'm a developer myself (a c++/go fan and mostly in machine learning area) I want to know what are the best options to choose when such thing is needed. I personally think that the whole back-end should work as a RESTful API and then probably something like react and react-native in front for both web and mobile but I'm not sure if this is the best decision we can make.

I want to know what other people with same requirements have done ? Some people recommended us meteor but it seems to be changing very fast and we really need some stable and mature solution without too much maintenance.

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions

Comment: The question itself is really opinionated, there is no way any answer will be clearly the *best*.

That said, for the front end, *an* option that I would consider today if I needed broad app support would be to use node tooling for a web based interface using React with material-ui or bootstrap@4, then use Cordova for iOS/Android and electron for Windows/Mac/Linux support.  Most of the codebase would be broadly reusable and target just about every common platorm for native-like.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes this is opinionated but that is exactly what I'm looking for because everyone comes with an option and that lets me to find more about the alternatives I didn't know. And to be honest, I was searching about this topic for a week and information I got was so sparse. Now I'm trying to make a list of all options I have then trying to find cost (finding developer, server, ...), maintainability, stability and many more factors of each option to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the REST API + front-end JS framework architecture.

One option would be to build an API with Ruby on Rails. The "rails generate new" command includes an --api option for generating a Rails application that lacks views and serves JSON. You can learn more about building APIs with Rails on the rails-api gem GitHub page. (Keep in mind the rails-api gem has since been rolled into Rails proper.)

Overall, Rails is a fast way to get a services layer up and running. It's fairly simple, and might be a good option for your app, which as you said, provides just one service. However, Rails is also powerful enough to support a much more substantial API.

If you want a REALLY simple Ruby-based services layer, you should check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). You could also go full Javascript with [Express](http://expressjs.com/). It's about as simple as Sinatra.

If you have a background with C++ and Go, you may not want to jump headfirst into these web-heavy technologies. Consider using Java Spring for your services layer. (I would link but I don't have enough rep. Haha)

As far as the front-end goes, you're on the right track with React and Meteor. I'm personally a fan of Angular (specifically Angular 2). It's a really popular JS web app framework -- great for asynchronous Javascript and single page applications. Granted, Angular has a steep learning curve to start, but if you're willing to climb, it pays off.

Let me know if you have any specific questions! Good luck.

Comment: So if I want to go with Go then what is your suggestion for the back-end ?

Comment: I haven't any experience with Go, but I found a few good resources on building REST JSON APIs with the language.[This describes (https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_3) and

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't finished! Anyway, I haven't any experience with Go, but I found a few good resources on building REST JSON APIs with the language. [This blog post](http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/) is a good  introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is a bit heavy if all you want is a web site. It depends how much interactivity you want - if it's more of an app, then it's worthwhile doing, and if you want to do ios and android apps, then Meteor is pretty fast to get up and running.

I would recommend to choose a technology that either you are keen to learn, or you have some skills in already. Learning curves mean longer projects.

Comment: There are 2 problems with Meteor. first it seems they are changing things very fast like dropping blaze and moving to react and then now they are dropping DDP going for Apollo, and the second one is the number of developers because as I said we need to hire developers and many js developers that pretend to know Meteor are not very familiar with js itself !

Comment: I don't think "dropping DDP" is at all a valid statement. The Javascript world is evolving fast, it's not just MDG doing that, Angular just went to v2, React still isn't actually up to 1.0 yet. Apollo gives you more options. I acknowledge the number of Meteor developers is still small, but Meteor still is up there on the Github stars list

Comment: DeBergalis from MDG in Meteor 1.4 and beyond talks mentioned : "we're committed to a path where you'll be able to use these different pieces together as we figure out the right time for a transition for Apollo to be the new default data layer." so most people thinking that in future DDP will be handed to community for support just like blaze.

Comment: He's talking about the data layer, not the data protocol.

Comment: Yes but as apollo can work over http then because meteor decided once not to have it's own developed front-end then again they many might think the same thing can happen again about DDP. Of course it might not happen at all. As you said the whole javascript world is evolving fast and thats why I'm a little concerned about meteor. And I forgot to reply to the learning curve part, we are going to hire people for doing most parts of the project so I only have to learn just basics to be able to understand what and why.

Comment: Two thing that are guaranteed: life in the IT world is complicated, and we don't know what's coming next :) Good luck with the project

Answer (score 0):

If you need native mobile application and interactive site than `react` and `react-native` with pure API server is a really good solution. I developed several similar services and very satisfied with this combination.

First of all you can share API access layer and part of business logic between both clients.
Second you are using identical technologies on mobile and web. However mobile application has real native UI because React Native don't use browser.
Thirdly server becomes more simple, maintainable and scalable.

Personally I prefer WebSockets as network protocol (look at amazing Go gorilla websocket implementation). But if you need support old browsers or prefer more classic REST API than it's ok also.

Comment: Thanks, and for back-end what do you suggest ? Go, JS, Python , ... I have seen Go gorilla but as I'm a Go developer myself (not a go web developer) I know that there are some problems in writing a Go back-end for example when you want to send a GET request through proxy, Go by default uses environment proxy and it is hard to find any alternative package which implements simple proxy management. I prefer myself to use Go but I'm not sure about other alternatives that might reduce the cost hugely while providing good stability.

Comment: All this options will be ok. Go plays well on backend ground. This is one of purpose this language was developed. Very fast and simple for deploying (one binary file as you know). Gin or Gorilla will be good choose for REST API. Python has tons of useful libraries. Try Flask if you will choose this language. Look at Sails if you will decide to go full javascript. Express or Koa if you need more low level control. Of course if you need more interactive level you will need another libraries and framework. For node it can be deepstream, Apollo, Feathers, Kuzzle or other depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on my comment above, this is all opinionated, but I find that Node/JavaScript tends to be about the best bang for the buck, if all you are trying to do is get through proof of concept stage, and possibly scaling from there.  Depending on your back-end needs, you may want to migrate parts, or whole to Go or Python.

On the Front end, using web tooling (mostly centered around node and npm), I would build the primary UI with React and the material-ui components... Targeting a web/browser interface... you can then extend this, in order to support more native-like features.  You can build "native" versions using Cordova for Android and iOS.  You can use electron as a base for desktop versions.

For the backend, node is a nice place to start, and I feel RethinkDB is a great database for *many* use cases (despite the changes from commercial to open platform happening now).  Mongo is another option, and there are hosted/managed options through a few providers.  Alternatively, I'd probably lean towards PostgreSQL via Amazon.

The API server, I'd definitely do a first pass with Node, and then, as needed rewrite whole, or in parts with Go or Python...  Go will have better performance and scale without compromising some of the ease of development aspects.  Python has very rich tooling, if you need more flexibility than performance for some areas.  There are other options, C# is becoming a very good cross-platform option, which I happen to really appreciate as a language.  The performance there is very good, though you may find some constraints less appealing than JS or Python.

YMMV with any of these choices.

Comment: And what framework will you choose for making an API with node ? (options with node are many times more than other)

Comment: Recommend Cordova after React is very strange. React Native will be much better choose. It is faster and has real native UI. I caution refrain from using RethinkDB also. RethinkDB company closed in October and the future of this project is uncertain.

Comment: The recommendation is because you will be able to have more code reuse (views) with Cordova than you will with ReactNative... you should be able to re-use state management and interfaces if you're using something like Redux for control flow, but the UI and many integration points will be different with ReactNative vs Desktop.. unless you use the MacNative and Reactnative for UWP (windows), which still will have a lot of variance.

Comment: Beyond this, most applications run well enough under Cordova, it isn't great for a lot of uses though... it will depend.